# In Javascript: Why new Date('2012-1-15') - new Date('2012-01-15') == 21600000

Tags: javascript

I'm confused but in javascript:

```
> new Date('2012-1-15') - new Date('2012-01-15')
  21600000
```

Why is that? (21600000 / 1000 / 3600 == 6 hours)

Comment: It prints here 14400000, which is 4 hours. I'm at GMT-4. That's likely related :)

Comment: Fails for me - the 2012-1-15 returns invalid date instead of a date object (FF 9.0.1), causing the whole thing to return NaN.

Comment: I get 18000000, 5 hours, and I am GMT-5... I'm with @BalusC on this one.

Comment: You are right, I'm at GMT-6 :)

Comment: Doesn't do it for me, equals zero: http://jsfiddle.net/LWdFn/4/

Comment: @Jivings: you *live* at GMT. That jsfiddle shows 14400000 to me.

Comment: @Marc: I tested in Chrome. It indeed returns NaN in Firefox and IE. Seems to be Webkit specific.

Comment: `new Date('2012-1-15')` returns "Invalid Date" in Opera.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The date format `yyyy-mm-dd` (2012-01-15) is parsed as being a UTC date while `yyyy-m-dd` (2012-1-15) is parsed as a local date. This is shown if you use `.toString` on each.

```
> (new Date( '2012-01-15' )).toString()
"Sat Jan 14 2012 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
> (new Date( '2012-1-15' )).toString()
"Sun Jan 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

Note that I am in California, hence the Pacific Standard Time. If you are in a different time zone you will get different results.

When JavaScript parses dates it tries formats used in more areas (such as UTC) first before it tries localized date formats. The last part of the UTC date format is a timezone offset from GMT which is assumed to be 0 when it is missing (as it is in this example). To get the same date you would need the full UTC timestamp: 2012-01-15T00:00:00-08:00.

Comment: it would be interesting to know /why/ this happens.

Comment: @Hamish I added a bit of an explanation, let me know if I should go more in depth.

Comment: Very odd, since then how should 2012-10-15 be parsed? it can't be both utc AND local.

Comment: @MarcB that would be parsed as a UTC date, since JS matches that format first which is why it is dangerous to mix date formats.

Comment: yay webkit, for having a very silly deviation from the JS standard, then.

Comment: Your code example shows that both are being parsed in the same way.

Comment: Hamish, you can see the *why* in Jukka's answer.

Comment: They are not parsed the same way. The difference is in the hours: 16 versus 00

Answer (score 10):

The result of `new Date('2012-1-15')` is implementation-dependent ([ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), clause 15.9.4.2).

Answer (score 7):

```
a= new Date('2012-1-16') 
b= new Date('2012-01-16')
alert(a);
alert(b);
```

For the first case, the constructor function sets time to 00:00 in your time zone. But in the second case, it initialize time relative to GMT +00.00